# error : module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer' what is the solution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
# the equation is  : 4x+2 = 0
unknownvalue = tf.Variable(0.0)

a = tf.constant(4.0)
b = tf.constant(2.0)
c = tf.multiply(unknownvalue,a)  # 4x
equation  = tf.add(c,b) # 4x+2
zerovalue = tf.constant(0.0)
diff = tf.square(equation-zerovalue) # differnce is : 4x+2  -  0 
solving = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(diff)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
tf.print(init)
for n in range(1000):
    tf.print(solving)
```

The code was written in the new version from his tensorflow library
The program does not run because of this error and it is
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer'
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tensorflow 2 has the gradient descent located in keras.optimizers, change it to this: `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD().minimize(var_list=diff)`

Packages have been moved around and reorganized.

Here is a link that will show you the changes that you need to make in order to transition your code from using tensorflow 1 to tensorflow 2: [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#keras_optimizers)

Comment: when i use your answer i have an new error  :: TypeError: minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list'

Comment: Here is information about minimize: [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD#minimize)